# VS SQL Server Database project (SSDT) compare project schema against database with linked server / server variable

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I have a VS SQL Server project that has linked server in it.
The linked server was added as a reference database (.dacpac) with database location set to "Different database, Different server".
I removed the database variable but VS will not let me remove the server variable.
So I have $(OtherServer) as the server variable.

Now my problem is that anytime I try to compare the database project against the database, it tells me the [$(OtherServer)] does not match the database.

Example:
Sproc in the database project has

```
SELECT * FROM [$(OtherServer)].Test.dbo.TestTable;
```

But on the server, the sproc has

```
SELECT * FROM TestServer.Test.dbo.TestTable;
```

Questions:

1. Is there some way of removing the "Server Variable" like you can the "Database Variable"?
   I tried to manually do this it the *.sqlproj file by changing "ServerSqlCmdVariable" to "ServerVariableLiteralValue" like it does for database variable but that did not work.
2. How do you compare a sql server database project when using server variable?

It looks like Schema Compare only does text compare even if I build the database project, it still thinks the the proc has changed.
This is not only procs, views and triggers seem to have issue when running Schema Compare in VS 2015.

**Steps to Reproduce Issue**

1. Create blank SQL Server Project in VS
2. Right-click on project and choose "Import Database"
3. Choose a database that has a proc or view with a linked server
4. Add a database reference to the *dacpac of the linked server into
   the project
5. For Database Location choose "Differen Database, Different Server"
6. Add the "Database Name" but leave "Database Variable" blank.
7. Add the "Server Name" and add the "Server Variable" as $(OtherServer)
8. Edit all sql scripts in the database project that use a linked
   server to now include [$(OtherServer)]
9. Right click on the project and build.
10. Right click on the project and choose "Schema Compare"

Once compare has finished, it will tell you that all procs / view that have [$(OtherServer)] don't match the database.

Posted feedback here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3105733